# Can´t import stl header with android studio 2.1.2

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk

i have a problem with android studio 2.1.2
i want to write some code in c++. In Gradle i insert the following code.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.glm.lichtschnitt"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    renderscriptTargetApi 19

    ndk {
        moduleName "Verarbeitungs-lib"
        ldLibs "log"
        cFlags "-pthread -frtti -fexceptions -std=c++11 -std=c11"

        stl "c++_static"

    }
    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = ["src/main/jni"]
        //jniLibs.srcDir
    }
}





buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        ndk {
            debuggable = true
        }
    }
    debug {
        debuggable = true
        jniDebuggable = true
    }
}
sourceSets { main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/java/swig'] } }
  }

  dependencies {
       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
       testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
       compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
  }
```

In studio 1.5 i can import all headers like "vector.h" or "list.h" 
In 2.1.2 i have no code completion. I can compile it but android studio has no code completion or something else for better code writing with the stl headers.

Is this a bug or can i do something to have the code completion. With 1.5 i have problems with native debugging on android 6.0.1, which is the reason why i ask for 2.1.2.

I use the newest nkd 12. I tried it also with ndk 10. same problem.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195483) they didn't fix it yet. Android studio still doesn't understand any header files.
I have the same trouble. You may try to change

`sourceSets.main {jni.srcDirs = ["src/main/jni"]}`

to

`sourceSets{main{jni{srcDirs = []}}}` ,

but it wont fix all problems

**UPDATE**

Since Google made some preview versions of Android Studio 2.2 there is quiet good support of different build systems for native code (CMake, Android.mk makefile, ndk-build)

Now I use AS 2.2 preview 6 with CMake and I have no troubles with linkig code or something else. There is still trouble with native debugger, but I think, I made something wrong.

To use Cmake for example, you could add to you gradle script following lines:

```
defaultConfig {
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
        }
    }

externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path 'src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt' //this is path to you build script
    }
}
```

So, if you don't afraid of non-release versions of AS, you could use it, it's good enough for native code

Comment: So I must use 1.5 for development and I wait for google -.-